# Eclipselink Static Weaving and Spring Boot is not Working

Tags: maven, spring-boot, eclipselink

In a Spring Boot project we use Eclipselink as ORM. We configured the build to weave statically and to package as jar. The interesting thing is that starting the program with `mvn spring-boot:run` works without problem, but starting with `java -jar archive.jar` works only if all entities are listed in the persistence.xml. Without having the class in the persistence.xml I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No [ManagedType] was found for the key class [eltest.Customer] in the Metamodel - please verify that the [Managed] class was referenced in persistence.xml using a specific <class>eltest.Customer</class> property or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element
```

Also in the case, when we package the program as war, it starts without issues.

My questions are: Does the `mvn spring-boot:run`invoke the static weaving at all, or does it weave at load-time? The same with the war deployment: does the war-build really invoke the static weaving, or is the weaving implicitly triggered, when the Tomcat starts the app? Is there a way to avoid listing the classes in the persistence.xml, and still go for statical weaving in a jar-packaging?

Here is an example:

https://github.com/gfinger/eltest

Build it with `mvn clean package`. If you start it with `mvn spring-boot:run` it uses Spring Data Rest to expose a Customer entity as REST resource. If you start it with `java -jar target/static-eclipselink-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` you get an error.

Comment: Check this question, it should be similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891205/how-to-ensure-load-time-weaving-takes-place-for-eclipselink-when-using-springboo/39891916#39891916

Comment: No, my question is about stativ weaving. The way how I package and start the app makes a difference, and I do not unterstand why.