# @SpringBootTest interferes with EclipseLink dynamic weaving

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, junit, eclipselink, load-time-weaving

My company is developing a web application using Spring Boot, Spring MVC, JPA with EclipseLink and dynamic weaving. 
My task is to prepare implementation of UI and integration tests spinning up the application using JUnit and @SpringBootTest and interacting with it using Selenium.

As stated at [Spring Boot Testing Features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html),
Tests using the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation can make use of the `@MockBean` annotation to define Mockito mocks for beans within the ApplicationContext. 
This is achieved by registering a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`, `MockitoPostProcessor`, recursively scanning classes annotated with `@Component` or `@Configuration` for classes and fields annotated with `@MockBean`.

Unfortunately, this causes the entity classes referenced in those classes to be loaded before the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` that is supposed to scan for them is instantiated and set up with a `LoadTimeWeaver`, thus causing the load time weaving for those entities to be skipped. 
This leads to `NoSuchMethodException`s for methods created by weaving like `_persistence_propertyChange()` when persistence actions are performed.

Is it possible to use `@SpringBootTest` with EclipseLink and dynamic weaving?
If not, what would be a good alternative to set up an integration test 
for a recent Spring Boot version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a custom `SpringApplicationRunListener`'s `contextPrepared()` to remove the problematic `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`s from the `ApplicationContext` before they got executed by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same problem in a web app built with Spring Boot 2.1.6 and EclipseLink 2.7.6.

> Is it possible to use @SpringBootTest with EclipseLink and dynamic weaving? If not, what would be a good alternative to set up an integration test for a recent Spring Boot version?

The solution was to set `eclipselink.weaving` JPA property to `false` in `@SpringBootTest`, and to `true` in regular operation.

Persistence config:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="eclipselink.weaving">${jpa.eclipselink.weaving}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <!-- ... -->
</bean>
```

Then in `application.properties`:

```
jpa.eclipselink.weaving=true
```

And on JUnit test class:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = "jpa.eclipselink.weaving=false")
```